# Javascript - how to convert decimal value to datetime

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to convert a decimal number to a date object in Javascript. I have tried multiple methods and using moment, but all my conversions are wrong. An example of a value I want to convert is 705623516.402048. I have tried to interpret the int part as seconds and the decimal part as milliseconds, but it has gone wrong too.

I cannot use JQuery, just plain JS or moment

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: `new Date(number * 1000)`

Comment: What date is that supposed to represent?

Comment: The number represents today (more or less right now)

Comment: You said that the int part is seconds. Seconds from when? Normally the base is 1970-01-01. But when I use that, I get a date in 1992.

Comment: I don't know, I just receive the number from an outside source, it is supposed to represent current date time

Comment: You need to know. There's no way to interpret it without that information.

Comment: I did some calculations and it appears to be seconds since 2001-01-01 00:00:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's supposed to be today's date, it looks like it's seconds since 2001-01-01. So you can use `Date.setSeconds()` to add to that date.

```js
let seconds = 705623516.402048;
let date = new Date('2001-01-01 00:00:00');
date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + seconds);
console.log(date);
```

Comment: I am doing right now the test and it works !!!! Thanks a lot

Comment: Epochs are typically UTC, so `let date = new Date(Date.UTC(2001,0))` might be a better choice. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The time value appears to be microseconds. Based on Barmar's answer, you can maintain millisecond precision (the best ECMAScript Dates can do currently) using:

```js
let seconds = 705623516.402048;
let date = new Date(Date.UTC(2001, 0) + seconds * 1e3);

console.log(date);
```

Date epochs are typically UTC (though not certainly), hence the use of *Date.UTC*.